# Web Api referencing old assemblies in temporary ASP.Net files

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-5.0, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Silverlight client that's hosted in an ASP.Net Web Api. If I run my project I get the following:

[image: Server Error]

I have recently restructured and cleaned up my solution but broke a couple of references which I managed to fix again. Clearly I missed something - **why is the project referencing a file from the**

> AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.Net Files\

**directory which is using an old assembly name?**

I've checked all references in web.config, cleaned up all my .Net temp folders, cleaned my solution and rebuilt however the problem persists. I've also deleted my bin\ and obj\ folders just to make sure but same error.

Can anyone guide me on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the only solution I could muster was to recreate the web project.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options for the issue you described:

1. The new WebApi.dll needs to be copied over in your **bin** directory and your web.config should not include, version, culture and PublicKeyToken details.
   or
2. Your new WebApi.dll needs to be in the **GAC** (C:\Windows\Assembly) and your web.config should contain at least a valid PublicKeyToken.

Comment: Do I copy the new dll to my SL client **bin**? I'm not sure I follow the web.config not including version, culture and pub key token statement.

Comment: Silverlight has it own subset of libraries that are allowed and since WebApi is server side technology most likely it is not event included the Client Profile version(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912(v=vs.110).aspx)